# C#, right click in internet explorer using watin

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, watin, right-click

Using WatiN, I'm loading up http://maps.google.com/

All I want to do is right click the map and click "Center map here" when the context menu pops up.

Another great feature would be to be able to "drag and drop" the mouse on the map so as to make the map scroll.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thankyou very much,
Fidel

Comment: did you have any luck with this in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the NativeMethods class in WatiN and add the functionality for right click through the use of the User32.dll. The thing to remember with doing it this way is that the page will have to have focus for this to work and you will have to know the location of the item in which you are clicking on.

http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html

Just a thought. I know it is not the best or only answer but it might get you unstuck for now.

-Todd